# What is the best way for using typo3 content in an android app?

Tags: android, content-management-system, typo3

What I want to do is, that I want to use some content from my typo3 Website in my Android app.

But there are many ways I could chose, to get the content from the typo3 Website - and I dont know which one would be The best. What Advantages and disadvantages IT would have.

1)I could read from the Database and parse the  content into My app.

2)I could parse See Website itself..

The big disadvantage would be if some structure is changed on Website the parsing would Not Work, i think.

or I will

3) manually Put in the content into the app (but there would be Many Work if the content is getting updated every Week..)

4) let the app get the content from an extern file(HTML, PHP with backend for content input Edit and delete.)

So, Do you have an idea which would be The best idea for solving my Problem ?
Maybe you have experience with these already, and Can give me a Clue.. The

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not try to parse HTML from the website itself, since structure may change and also you may load/parse much overhead, that is not needed by the app.

Putting content directly into the app is also a bad idea, since you have to release app updates on every content change and users may not always update their app. Also keep in mind, that each App update (for iOS) requires a review by Apple, which may take some days before the App (or updated App) finally becomes public available.

The best way to go is to create an REST API on the TYPO3 side (e.g. TYPO3 Extension, PHP application, NodeJS application), which reads the desired content from the TYPO3 database.

Some of the advantages of an REST API are:

- You control the content structure
- No content overhead and lightweight data structure (JSON)
- If performance of the REST API is bad due to heavy usage, then you can inplement caching or you can replace the API with a faster/better version
- Usage on all mobile platforms is the same

Generally you should first point out, which content you want to deliver to your app. If you for example want the app to get news from e.g. tt_news or tx_news, then the requirements to the REST API are easy to implement, since you "just" have to deal with the tables from the desired extensions and the content structure may not be very complex.

If you want to retreive TYPO3 pages and page content on that pages, then things become more complicated, since you have to deal with many different scenarios (e.g. multilingual content, content sorting) and page content may not only be text, but also plugins, HTML, media and so on, so you also have to take care of that.

Hope this helps you choosing the right method to retrieve the content from TYPO3.

Comment: I can only agree ;) just wanted to write the same, good elaborated

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my thoughts were nearly the same.